# please who can help me to solve this error in under unix

Tags: c, unix

```
client.c:60:17: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'int *' [-Wformat]

client.c:63:17: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'int *' [-Wformat]
```

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc , char ** argv)
{

        if(argc != 3)  //check for parameters
        {
                printf("usage : a.out <IP=127.0.0.1> <Port number=22033>\n");
                return 0;
        }
    //int x;
        int             sockfd , port = 0 ;
        int            intger[101] , buff[101];
        struct sockaddr_in      servaddr;

        port = atoi(argv[2]);  //convert port number from string to integer


        bzero(&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));  //reset the servaddr
        servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        servaddr.sin_port   = htons(port);
        inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &servaddr.sin_addr);

        sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);  //new socket

        bzero(buff,101);  //reset the buffer
    bzero(intger,101);  //





connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)); //connect to the server
                bzero(buff,101); //reset the buffer


//for(;;){

                printf("Please Enter an Integer :");

                scanf("%d", intger); //reading from the user

                write(sockfd , intger , 300);   //sending the integer to the server

                printf("Sending %d to the server\n" , intger);

                printf("Waiting for server reply ...\n");

                read(sockfd , buff , 300);

                printf("Received %d from the server\n" , buff);

                //bzero(buff,300);

                printf("\n");
//}

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: John Kugelman i have apload the code

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you are doing something like this `printf("%d",x);`, as you have not posted any code.

In the above example, you would seem to be passing `x` as an `int*`. printf is expecting an `int`.

EDIT: Looking at your code, you are using `printf` and passing `intgr`, but `intgr` is an array.

So, for your line of code:

`printf("Sending %d to the server\n" , intger);`

It should be something like this (which prints the first item in the array):

`printf("Sending %d to the server\n" , intger[0]);`

Comment: what's about this
server.c:(.text+0x1b8): undefined reference to `str_echo'

Comment: It means str_echo can't be found - missing header file or library not linked. This is a separate issue though. Mark this as the answer if it answered your original question please.

Comment: what is the header file for echo? please @Phil_12d3

Comment: I don't know. I did quick google (which you could have done too) to get this: 

http://82.157.70.109/mirrorbooks/unixnetworkprogramming/0131411551_ch14lev1sec8.html

http://www.cs.odu.edu/~cs779/stevens2nd/lib/str_echo.c

http://www.kumouse.com/doc/UNIX_Network_%20Programming_Volume_1/0131411551_ch05lev1sec3.html

Comment: i did but there wasn't any answer that can help me
and thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't printf("%d",&x);

work ? if it's a pointer to int, the data it points to is int, or have I completely forgotten all the C I knew ?

Comment: It's `*x` if `x` is of type `int*`. `&x` would be of type `int**` otherwise.